# how do I create a wide-format data entry form if data is stored in long form in django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

Suppose I have a model for 'species' and a model for geographic 'locations'.

```
class species(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class location(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I also have a third model `occurrences` that keeps track of occurrences of species at locations. (I realized I could also use a many-to-many field with a through table, but this is legacy code so I would prefer to keep it as is).

```
class occurrences(models.Model):
   species = models.ForeignKey(species)
   location = models.ForeignKey(location)
```

Ideally, I would like users to be able to enter new `occurrences` in a wide-table format.  So schematically, the html form would look like this, with checkboxes:

```
                  | Location1 | Location2 | 
         SpeciesA |     x     |           |          
         SpeciesB |           |     x     |
```

When this form gets submitted it would create two new `occurrences` (SpeciesA at Location1, and SpeciesB at Location2).

**This seems like a use case that others must have had, because users like spreadsheet formats. Is there a pre-existing django solution for allowing users to enter data in this format?**

Comment: Have you been able to sort this out?

Comment: Not yet.  I think you are right that my life would be easier if I used a formal many-to-many

Answer (score 1):

Building a `ManyToMany` relationship with these models will not break your existing code nor will it make any changes to the database. In fact you already have a `ManyToMany`, you just have to mark it as such.

```
class species(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   species_locations = models.ManyToManyField(Locations,through='Occurrences')
```

When you run the migration you will note that it doesn't actually make any changes to the database.

Additionally, you have an error in this model.

```
class occurrences(models.Model):
   species = models.ForeignKey(location)
   location = models.ForeignKey(location)
```

I do believe you intended `species` to be a foreign key to `Species`

The second part of the problem is mostly in HTML rendering, the django component to be used is [InlineFormSet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-methods-on-an-inlineformset) this allows related models to be edited easily. (you do not need ManyToMany here if the Occcurence model is what's been edited in the form)